# Bandwidth share (master => workers)

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am working on transfer protocol ,I have a master and many workers ,so my need is how to divide bandwidth of master for workers .
Each worker have a number of data to send , as a first solution I have specified a fixed number of connection (socket) for master and for fixing cnx number of a worker I use this formula

```
(data number of workers / Sum Data to master) * cnx number of master
```

I am not sure if I am in the right way .
Any ideas !!!

Comment: Do each of the workers always want to send their maximum data length? Is this length the same for all workers? Does the master want to send data?

Comment: We need to all workers finish at the same time or nearly , each worker must send all data , and data size is the same for all workers , the master only receive

Comment: About how large is this amount of data?

Comment: Ethernet should be able to deal with the possible collisions.

Comment: Data size is 500 MBytes

Comment: I should have been more clear. How often does this 500 MB have to be transmitted from each worker?